# Python logging messages appears in stdout when script is launched

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'm setting a logging feature in my test script, but when I run it all messages are appearing on the console(stdout), the log file is written ok, how can I avoid this behaviour? I only want the messages are in the log file. Thanks.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILE = "/var/log/mylog.log"
logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=10*1024*1024, backupCount=5)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
....
```

Comment: Don't want messages on a console - remove the `StreamHandler` or increase the level of it, e.g. to `ERROR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alecxe said, you should change your console_handler code to:

```
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
console_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting it yourself here:

```
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html